# Occasionally Missing Return Parameter id_token

Tags: google-oauth

When using the Google OAuth2 API, I am receiving inconsistent reply parameters.

scopes: ['email','profile']

Expected Response:

```
{ 
  access_token: 'ya29.fQB...aYSwXTK7Etm2XzIhA2VYf7Gtp',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3600,
  id_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsI...bDkzZDNjYzFicWJmdTIzdjF...pZWRfZW1h...0vYWNjb3Vud...kSObTnsLQKg...3Mpg6Y2K2Bhw6c' 
}
```

Received Response:

```
{ 
  access_token: 'ya29.fQDvVUn66q...vqe2WLQf_Nc4d4oc',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3600 
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem or work around it?

Comment: I am having the same issue but only today. (Sep 11)

Comment: Same for me, this issue has only appeared today.

Comment: Same problem here, I wonder if it's a bug. Any way to escalate to google?

Comment: The issue I have is that I can get id_token, but id_token doesn't have email_verified and email scope.

Comment: Seems to be working aging for me.

Comment: Received word from Google that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Same issue here, although it recently went away and combined with @toohool's comment I guess we can consider this resolved.
There is some related talk at this issue if anybody is interested: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/183

toohool, how did you get in touch with Google about this (for future reference)?

Comment: my errors also seem to have abated. voting to close this as it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this was caused by an issue with our latest release and we rolled back as soon as we came to know about it.﻿
So this should be resolved (as of 2pm PST). If you are still seeing issues do let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the clarification Naveen,
Amplify.com education application faced this issue around 2:30pm Sep 11, 2014 Eastern and it was fixed around 5:15pm EST same day.  Our authentication is based on Google OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

For us to be prepared, Are you/Google planning on removing the email ID from the Google API in the future, or was that a development bug that was corrected?
Thanx,

Comment: No this was just a bug. There is no plan to remove the email address (if a user has agreed to share). That doesn't make sense.